# How to Get Sum of One Column Based On Other Table in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sum

I have 2 table in my database (like this):

```
tblCustomers:

id    CustomerName
1     aaa
2     bbb
3     ccc
4     ddd
5     eee
6     fff
```

---

```
tblPurchases:

id    CustomerID    Price
1     1             300
2     2             100
3     3             500
4     1             150
5     4             50
6     3             250
7     6             700
8     2             30
9     1             310
10    4             25
```

Now I want with "Stored Procedures" take a new table that give me the sum of price for each customer. Exactly like under.

How can do that?

```
Procedures Result:

id    CustomerName    SumPrice
1     aaa             760
2     bbb             130
3     ccc             750
4     ddd             75
5     eee             0
6     fff             700
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select c.id, c.customername, sum(isnull(p.price, 0)) as sumprice
  from tblcustomers c
  left join tblpurchases p
    on c.id = p.customerid
 group by c.id, c.customername
```

SQL Fiddle test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b573/1/0

Note the need for an outer join because your desired result includes customers with no purchases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to get the result

```
   select id,CustomerName,sum(price) as TotalPrice
    from
    (
    select tc.id,tc.CustomerName,tp.price
    from tblCustomers tc
    join 
    tblPurchases tp on tc.id = tp.CustomerID  
    ) tab
    group by id,CustomerName
```

Comment: Why the sub-query?  It doesn't appear to be needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Although the other answers here do work, they don't appear to be what I would consider standard practice, or optimal.

The simplest solution (standard, but not always optimal) requires no sub-query of any variety.

```
SELECT
  cust.id,
  cust.CustomerName,
  SUM(prch.price)   AS SumPrice
FROM
  tblCustomers   AS cust
INNER JOIN
  tblPurchases   AS prch
    ON  cust.id = prch.CustomerID
GROUP BY
  cust.id,
  cust.CustomerName
```

The only reason that this is not necessarily optimal is that it involves grouping by two fields, one of which is a string.  This involves creating 'counters' in memory that are identified by this composite of an *id* and *string*, which can be inefficient due to the fact that you only really need to use the *id* to uniquely identify the counter.  *(The identifier is only one item and is a small (probably only 4 bytes), rather than multiple items one of which is long (potentially many many bytes))*.

This means that you can do the following as a possible optimisation.  Though depending on your data this many be a premature optimsation, it has no performance down-side and is always good to know about...

```
SELECT
  cust.id,
  cust.CustomerName,
  prch.SumPrice
FROM
  tblCustomers   AS cust
INNER JOIN
  (
  SELECT
    CustomerID,
    SUM(price) AS SumPrice
  FROM
    tblPurchases
  GROUP BY
    CustomerID
  )              AS prch
    ON  cust.id = prch.CustomerID
```

This makes the in-memory aggregation as simple as possible, as so as quick as possible.

In both cases you should have the best possible efficiency in the query by ensuring that you have indexes on `tblCustomer(id)` and on `tblPurchases(CustomerID)`,

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tblcustomers table  (id int, customername varchar(10));

insert into @tblcustomers values (1, 'aaa');
insert into @tblcustomers values (2, 'bbb');
insert into @tblcustomers values (3, 'ccc');
insert into @tblcustomers values (4, 'ddd');
insert into @tblcustomers values (5, 'eee');
insert into @tblcustomers values (6, 'fff');

DECLARE @tblpurchases table  (id int, customerid int, price int);

insert into @tblpurchases values (1, 1, 300);
insert into @tblpurchases values (2, 2, 100);
insert into @tblpurchases values (3, 3, 500);
insert into @tblpurchases values (4, 1, 150);
insert into @tblpurchases values (5, 4, 50);
insert into @tblpurchases values (6, 3, 250);
insert into @tblpurchases values (7, 6, 700);
insert into @tblpurchases values (8, 2, 30);
insert into @tblpurchases values (9, 1, 310);
insert into @tblpurchases values (10, 4, 25);

WITH CTE  AS(
select c.id,c.customername from @tblcustomers c
)
Select c.id,c.customername,(Select SUM(ISNULL(P.price,0)) from @tblpurchases P
WHERE P.customerid = C.id) AS Price  from  CTE c
```